# Why are there no variables showing up in inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to make a Tile system in Unity. I have my tile class done but when I create a list in the TileManager class it gives me the option to change the size of the list but gives me an empty element with no changeable variables.

Tile Class:

```
public class Tile : MonoBehaviour
{

public Sprite tileSprite;
public string tileName;
public int tileID;

public Tile(Sprite newTileSprite, string newTileName, int newTileID) 
{
    tileSprite = newTileSprite;
    tileName = newTileName;
    tileID = newTileID;
}

void Start()
{
    SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer)) as SpriteRenderer;

    if (spriteRenderer != null) spriteRenderer.sprite = tileSprite;
}
```

TileManager Class:

```
public class TileManager : MonoBehaviour {

public List<Tile> Tiles;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Comment: Based on the screenshot you have on the one answer, seems like it has null in the first element; null would have no properties to modify.

Comment: How would I fix that?

Comment: Another issue might be you have no editor for that type (Tile). Might try http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/editor/custom-list/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `System.Serializable` attribute on Tile class. Also be sure that the Tile class does not inherit from MonoBehaviour, otherwise it will still not appear in the inspector list.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Tile 
{
   public Sprite tileSprite;
   public string tileName;
   public int tileID;

   public Tile(Sprite newTileSprite, string newTileName, int newTileID) 
   {
       tileSprite = newTileSprite;
       tileName = newTileName;
       tileID = newTileID;
   }
}
```

Comment: Added it and I'm still just getting empty elements.

Comment: `public class TileManager {

public List<Tile> Tiles;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () 
 {

 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
  
 }
}
`

Comment: Okay add `[System.Serializable]` to TileManager as well. Generally, classes that aren't inheriting from MonoBehaviour or Unity.Object class will need the Serializable attribute for it to appear in the editor

Comment: I added it to both classes. Both classes also inherit MonoBehaviour.

Comment: Remove `: MonoBehaviour` extension from your `Tile` class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167844/discussion-between-liam-earle-and-aj).